# Using abstract classes and interfaces to sort arrays with algorithms

Tags: java, abstract-class

Hi I'm just learning how to use abstract classes and interfaces.  The code below is intended to be used by other classes to sort arrays in a number of different ways.

```
import java.util.Random;

public interface ArraySort {
// sorts the array using insertion sort

public default int[] sortInsertion(int[] array){
      int j;                     // the number of items sorted so far
      int key;                // the item to be inserted
      int i;  

      for (j = 1; j < array.length; j++)    // Start with 1 (not 0)
     {
            key = array[ j ];
            for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && (array[ i ] < key); i--)   // Smaller values are moving up
           {
                  array[ i+1 ] = array[ i ];
           }
          array[ i+1 ] = key;    // Put the key in its proper location
      }
    return array;
 }




// shuffles the array
public default int[] shuffle(int[] array){
    Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator         

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(array.length);
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randomPosition];
        array[randomPosition] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}









// prints the array elements
public default void print(int[] array){
    System.out.println(array);
}











// initialize array from firstElement to lastElement
public int[] init(int firstElement, int lastElement);








}
```

I would like to know if this is necessarily an appropriate implementation of an abstract interface.  Is there something that would make it much more efficient?  Is there a better way to be doing this?  What I want to know specifically is whether or not my code is 100% faithful to the concept of abstract classes and interfaces because I'm just trying to learn it in the best way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces define methods without implementation. A class will then implement the interface and provide the method body.

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Here is a [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

Comment: (Well, Java 8 changes that first statement slightly.)

Comment: But OPs implementation isn't what defaults are intended for. I guess this rather confusing for beginners.